# Show $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}{k \over \ln k} \le {n^2 \over \ln n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Why is it true that
$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}{k \over \ln k} \le {n^2 \over \ln n}, n \ge 2$$

I try to expand the term of the sum in Taylor series but it didn't help me.
I try to recognize the sum as a lower  Riemann sum of $\int{x \over \ln x}$, but it didn't help either.

Comment: I would try induction for a problem like this....

Comment: Hint: On $[e,\infty)$, the function $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ is increasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First dispose off the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ by explicit verification. We will henceforth assume $n \geq 4$.

Since the function 
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{\ln x}
$$
is increasing in $[e, \infty)$, it follows that
$$
\frac{k}{\ln k} \leq \frac{n}{\ln n} \tag{1}
$$
for $3 \leq k \leq n$. Also, assuming $n \geq 4$, we have 
$$
\frac{2}{\ln 2} = \frac{4}{\ln 4} \leq \frac{n}{\ln n}. \tag{2}
$$
Adding the inequalities $(1)$ (for $3 \leq k \leq n$) and $(2)$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{k}{\ln k} \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{\ln n},
$$
which implies the result.

Comment: Very clear argument. I've learn instantly from it. Thank you.